# merge two multidimensional array object and build a hierarchy as follow

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-merge

i have two arrays

```
[{id: 1,parent: 0,name: Sri lanka},{id: 2,parent: 1,name: Southern},{id: 3,parent: 1,name: Western},{id: 4,parent: 1,name: East},{id: 5,parent: 1,name: North},{id: 6,parent: 2,name: Galle},{id: 7,parent: 2,name: Hikkaduwa},{id: 8,parent: 3,name: Colombo},{id: 9,parent: 3,name: Nugegoda},{id: 10,parent: 4,name: Ampara},{id: 11,parent: 4,name: Monaragala},{id: 12,parent: 5,name: Jafna},{id: 13,parent: 5,name: Anuradhapura}]

[{id: 6,paulation: 40,size: 200},{id: 7,paulation: 100,size: 600},{id: 8,paulation: 700,size: 1200},{id: 9,paulation: 400,size: 800},{id: 10,paulation: 10,size: 600},{id: 11,paulation: 15,size: 500},{id: 12,paulation: 50,size: 700},{id: 13,paulation: 100,size: 2000}]
```

and i want merge these twos like this

```
[{id: 1,parent: 0,name: Sri lanka,{paulation: 1415,size: 6600}},{id: 2,parent: 1,name: Southern,{paulation: 140,size: 800}},{id: 3,parent: 1,name: Western,{paulation: 1100,size: 2000}},{id: 4,parent: 1,name: East,{paulation: 25,size: 1100}},{id: 5,parent: 1,name: North,{paulation: 150,size: 2700}},{id: 6,parent: 2,name: Galle,{paulation: 40,size: 200},{id: 7,parent: 2,name: Hikkaduwa,{paulation: 100,size: 600}},{id: 8,parent: 3,name: Colombo,{paulation: 700,size: 1200}},{id: 9,parent: 3,name: Nugegoda,{paulation: 400,size: 800}},{id: 10,parent: 4,name: Ampara,{paulation: 10,size: 600}},{id: 11,parent: 4,name: Monaragala,{paulation: 15,size: 500}},{id: 12,parent: 5,name: Jaffana,{paulation: 50,size: 700}},{id: 13,parent: 5,name: Anuradhapura,{paulation: 100,size: 2000}}]
```

[image]

I want to get each child node values total into parent node

Comment: I want to get each child node values total into parent node

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this? A `json` - `array` - `loop` can probably help.

Comment: how to use loop for this, these are sample data, in real case i have more than 1000 elements in my arrays

Comment: You can do it with MySQL

Comment: You have this Data on Database, and you can Use JOIN QUERY for this. it will be easy, for More see > http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: if you are using mysql, then you can refer [Link](https://referencekiru.wordpress.com/portfolio/display-cities-of-corresponding-country-in-jquery/)